# Use a Python regex to check a key:value;key:value; string is well-formed

Tags: python, regex

My Python program handles strings composed of id:value; pairs such as:

```
s = "1:name;2:another name;3:one last name;"
```

The id should always be numerical and the final ; is optional.
I'd like to implement a regex which both checks that the string is well-formed and does the splitting for me.

I wrote this:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'([0-9]+):([^:;]+)(?:;|$)*')
```

Which seems to do the splitting properly:

```
>>> dict(r.findall(s))
{'1': 'name', '3': 'one last name', '2': 'another name'}
```

The problem is I'd also like use my regex to catch malformed strings. Is there a way to change it so that the following operations fail?

```
>>> r.match("1:name;dummy:another name;3:one last name;")
>>> r.match("1:name;a2:another name;3:one last name;")
```

Thanks!
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform the match using a different regex which includes $ end of string, which will validate the string for you.

```
>>> validate = re.compile(r'(([0-9]+):([^:;]+)(?:;|$)*)*$')
>>> validate.match("1:name;2:another name;3:one last name;")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02B132A0>
>>> validate.match("1:name;dummy:another name;3:one last name;") # is None
>>> validate.match("1:name;a2:another name;3:one last name;") # is also None
```

I can't think of a way of using match and findall with the same regex for validation. But nor, do I think, would it be a good idea to do so.

**Here is an explanation as to why you cannot use the same regex for grouping and validation**:

You have to use `findall()` for getting an unknown number of groups, using a MatchObject simply will not work because it will not handle a variable number of groups.

So given this regex `R` that you are using for the `findall()` function, `R` must match a single expression in a string with a variable number of expressions. But there is no way to use `R` in a similar way for a `match()` call, because since `R` only matches one expression out of the variable number in the string, it is impossible to guarantee the content of the remainder of the string.

Comment: You mixed up `^` and `$` and `match` doesn't require `^` :)

Comment: ah, you are right, match doesn't require ^, but what do you mean by i mixed up ^ and $?

Comment: `^` is the start of the string and `$` is the end of string :)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I wouldn't use regex here. I would use a dict comprehension.

```
s = "1:name;2:another name;3:one last name;"
id_values = {k:v for entries in s.split(";") if entries for
            k,v in [entries.split(":")] if k.isdigit()}
print(id_values)
# {'1': 'name', '3': 'one last name', '2': 'another name'}

s2 = "1:name;dummy:another name;3:one last name;"
id_values_2 = {k:v for entries in s2.split(";") if entries for
              k,v in [entries.split(":")] if k.isdigit()}
print(id_values_2)
# {'1': 'name', '3': 'one last name'}
```